# 'YYSTYPE' has no member 

Tags: c++, c, parsing, yacc, lex

In my YACC file, I have this:

```
%union {
    Node *node;
    FuncParamList *fParam;
    CallParamList *cParam;
    char *str;
    struct {
        char *name;
        Node *node;
    } nameNodePair;
}
```

This is my Lex file (note that it includes the header file generated by YACC):

```
%{
    #include "yacc_parser.hh"
%}

%%

if              return IF;
ei              return ELSEIF;
else            return ELSE;
endif           return ENDIF;
while           return WHILE;
loop            return LOOP;
func            return FUNC;
end             return END;

:=              return ASSIGN;
\.              return DOT;
,               return COMMA;
:               return COLON;
\(              return OPAREN;
\)              return CPAREN;

(\n|\r\n?)      { /* increment line count */ return LF; }
;               return LF;

[!?A-Za-z][!?A-Za-z0-9]         { yylval.str = yytext; return NAME; }
[0-9]+                          { yylval.str = yytext; return INTEGER; }

%%
```

But I get this error when I compile:

```
/home/michael/Projects/lang/lib/lex_lexer.l:26:9: error: ‘YYSTYPE’ has no member named ‘str’
/home/michael/Projects/lang/lib/lex_lexer.l:27:9: error: ‘YYSTYPE’ has no member named ‘str’
```

I made sure that the YACC header file contains the YYSTYPE definition, and the Lex output file does include it before it uses YYSTYPE. What should I do?

Comment: What is your YYSTYPE definition?

Comment: @M'vy What do you mean? I posted it!

Comment: So the %union is in the header file? Just wanted to be sure of that.

Comment: About %union: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#index-g_t_0025union-172 . It's converted to a union called YYSTYPE by YACC.

Comment: Looks correct to me, so I suspect you have an old `yacc_parser.hh` that's not being rebuilt by your CMake build -- possibly running bison in a way that puts the output in some other filename (perhaps `yacc.parser.hh`?)  Check your make rules carefully, check the times on the files to make sure they make sense, and look at `yacc_parser.hh` to make sure it contains the expected code -- the contents of the definition of YYSTYPE should be an exact (character for character) copy of what is in your %union

Answer (score 1):

[should be a comment, but I need spacing and blanks to be readable. Will edit to make it real solution when all will be clarify]

Edit1: new conf
So let's clarify a bit the file you shall have :

C++ code style / `yacc_parser.yy` : containing the %union

C++ code style / `yacc_parser.hh` and `yacc_parser.cc` : generated by the `yacc yacc_parser.yy` command

C code style / `lex_lexer.l` : includes `yacc_parser.h`

C code style / `lex_lexer.c` : generated by `lex lex_lexer.l` command

Then you compile&link : `gcc -Wall lex_lexer.c yacc_parser.cc` that should produce the executable file.

Since you mix C and C++ code, I almost sure you need to use a `extern "C" { ... }` somewhere to link your union as a C type not C++. That may explain why you c code can't find the struct member.

Maybe

```
%union {
    extern "C" {
    ...teh code...
    }
}
```

for my information, why have you a mix of C and C++? why not only one language?

Comment: My configuration is quite different from what you described. I have yacc_parser.y (It's C++, I don't know whether it should be .y or .yy or if it matters). yacc_parser.hh and yacc_parser.cc are generated by yacc, and lex_lexer.c (C, not C++) is generated by lex from lex_lexer.l. I'm using CMake to build. I have no idea how to post the CMake file, though (since Stack Overflow doesn't work like a discussion forum).

Comment: Edited. I guess pastebin could serve for code sharing purpose.

Comment: About mixing C and C++: http://ds9a.nl/lex-yacc/cvs/lex-yacc-howto.html#s5 yacc_parser.y: http://pastebin.com/2rMAtWBJ lex_lexer.l: http://pastebin.com/BtXzRL3p

Comment: I don't have all your code, but does yacc_parser.hh includes your node header? I'm getting error from that one. And also same errors for the union.

Comment: Look at the code I posted in my previous comment. yacc_parser.y includes node.hh.

Comment: Yes but it is not included in the y.tab.h on my tests (your yacc_parser.hh). Could be the reason why the union is not well defined

Comment: So I should have a separate header defining YYSTYPE, and include that in `yacc_parser.y` and `lex_lexer.l`? I guess it would work, but why did they put the `%union` feature in YACC then?

Comment: Hum, I don't know how it was defined at the base, but I think lex and yacc were standalone apps at the beginning. would explain many things. I do not know if flex/bison behave the same.

Comment: As I understand, Flex and Bison are mde to be drop-in replacements for Lex and YACC. (and they have some extra features you can optionally use).

Comment: Did you just try to add include of node.h in the lex first section?

Comment: I just got really confused and lost track. Anyway one problem is that there's a C++ file (which uses C++-specific syntax) called config.hh, that's included by everything. The problem is that if it's included directly or indirectly into lex_lexer.l, then it fails because Lex's output is C, not C++. And also, this is the CMake file: http://pastebin.com/1g8kr7ny

Comment: Your lexer needs to know about Node structure, so one way or the other you have to make the declaration available to it. Maybe a simple forward declaration may work.